# Get reference to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, polymer

In `Polymer` you can use `this.$.idOfElement` to get an element with an `id` of `idOfElement`.

How can I get a dynamically created element by its `id` if I only have the value of `id` in a variable?

Note: The element I want to reach out to is created dynamically like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[days]]" as="o">
    <my-custom-element id$="[[getId(o)]]"></my-custom-element>
</template>
```

I have plenty of these `<my-custom-element>` in my app and need to get hold of them one by one.

**Edit:**

None of these work, they all return undefined or null:

```
this.$[id]
this.$$(id)
this.root.querySelector('my-custom-element#' + id)
Polymer.dom(e.currentTarget).querySelector('my-custom-element#' + id)
```

Comment: You mean like `this.$[id]`?

Comment: Question updated since this.$[idVar] does not work ... maybe related to the circumstances.

Comment: Have you tried `this.$$('#' + id)`?

Comment: @Alan No that one I did not try yet, but it looks promising. I'll try this evening and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the automatic node finder (`this.$.x`) for dynamic nodes. You have to use `this.$$(selector)`, which acts like `document.querySelector()` constrained to children of the current element.

This why you must use `this.$$('#' + nodeId)` as suggested by Alan.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  
  makeRed: function() {
    this.$$('#li2').style.color = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items='[ 1, 2, 3 ]'>
          <li id="li[[item]]">{{item}}</li>
        </template>
      </ul>
      
      <input type="button" value="make 2 red" on-tap="makeRed" />
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```